# Creating a dictionary variable in Vars folder then setting to dictionary variable in python

Tags: python, dictionary, module, ansible

I was wondering how to create a dictionary variable in the main.yml file inside a vars folder then setting that dictionary variable to a variable in a customer python module.

```
def main():
    module = AnsibleModule(
        argument_spec=dict(
            sl_username=dict(required=True),
            sl_api_key=dict(required=True),
            list_ips=dict(required=True),
            soft_reboot=dict(required=True),
            hard_reboot=dict(required=True)
        ),
        supports_check_mode=True
    )
```

so I have the `list_ips` variable in which I'm passing through as an argument from the vars folder:

```
...
soft_reboot: True
hard_reboot:
list_ips: "{{ server_ips }}"
```

Then setting in the custom module:

```
argumentDict = module.params.get('list_ips')
```

what's in the main.yml file inside the vars doesn't work:

```
---

server_ips: {
    "ip": ["1111.1111", "222.222.22.22"]
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? Are you getting an error? If so please supply it or the output you are getting to aide in understanding the problem

Answer (score 0):

If my guess is correct `list_ips` parameter name suggests it to be a list, not a dict. So try to modify your vars file:

```
server_ips: ["1111.1111", "222.222.22.22"]
```